# Javascript get Property name from class declaration

Tags: javascript, reflection

Lets have a javascript "class"

```
  var User= function(id, firstName, lastName) {
      this.id=id;
      this.firstName=firstName;
      this.lastName=lastName
  }
  var user = new User (1,"I", "am");
```

I would like to reference a specific field name of user class, lets say the id field, without using the String "id"

... something like `(user->id).getName();` (should return the String "id")

Note : Enumerating the user Object properties is not helping me since I will have to choose among them using the String "id" and so hard code somewhere

hope I am clear.

The goal is to select some properties of user Object to fill in a table without hard coding the object properties as Strings.
Thanks

Comment: So, essentially, you want to get an item out of a dictionary, without the key?

Comment: lol. The key exists, my question is : can I access it from a property class declaration

Comment: please elaborate what you want. I suppose you don't want to hardcode user["id"] and fetch id of the user.

Comment: This is exactly the question

Comment: This seems silly (Madara is right). However imagine each property defined as an object having a method getName(). This will help me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I try to implement it in PHP, for those interested : [the github link](https://github.com/thipages/TS_Class)

Comment: This does not answer the question nor does the link provide any useful solution for JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function. You will get an array of all the keys in your object.

```
var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
        Object.keys = Object_keys;
        function Object_keys(obj) {
            var keys = [], name;
            for (name in obj) {
                if (hasOwn.call(obj, name)) {
                    keys.push(name);
                }
            }
            return keys;
        }
```

Now, you don't have to hard code things. just store the function response to a var and use a loop to get values in order.

Comment: this enumerates the object properties, but I will have to String hardcode the key I want (eg "id")

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it could be to implement for each property a function with the same name accessed statically.

... but rather paintfull to write (need to duplicate each property declaration and error may append)

```
    var User= function(id, firstName, lastName) {
        this.id=id;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName
    };
    User.id=function()  {return "id"};
    User.firstName=function()  {return "firstName"};
    User.lastName=function()  {return "lastName"};
```

With it, I could access the name of the property without (too much) ambiguity like

```
var user = new User (1,"I", "am");
var myFieldList=[User.id(), User.firstName()];
```

instead of

```
var myFieldList=["id", "firstName"];
```